# What accounts for the weight of nearly empty .exe file?

Tags: c++, compilation, exe

I have this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
cout<<"Hi there!";
return 0;
}
```

Which I compiled via "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" using this line:

```
cl -GS name.cpp
```

Which in turn resulted in an executable file of 137kb in size. 
 
While I understand that 137kb is nothing in modern computing, it still seems like an awfully big file for the amount of code it runs. Moreover, trying to compile a similar code, but with an `int` variable adds another 15kb on top. What happens with an integer during compilation that it has to weight so much?

Comment: It's amazing isn't it? To think that Manic Miner rolled in at around 16k.

Comment: @Bathsheba Building a game using only one int (and extra 1K) variable is a godlike level!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default compiler options embeds the `MSVCRxxx.DLL` into the executable file, thing that doesn't happen running your same command with /MD option:

```
cl.exe /MD /EHsc name.cpp
```

With this command the executable size is **15KB** (with VS2013 x86 Native Tools).

This occurs because by default option launching the compiler is `/MT` while the default for projects built through Visual Studio is `/MD` (resulting in files near 15KB). With /MD option, the executable is smaller as doesn't have the library embedded in it.

Compiling and linking in two separated commands (default Visual Studio Release solution configuration commands):

```
cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /sdl /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _LIB /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo /Fd /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt name.cpp
```

This produces the object file that will be used in the next linking step.

```
link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"c:\Dev\namefromlinker.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Dev\name.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"c:\Dev\name.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH name.obj
```

This produces an executable file of **12KB**.

The compiler Options can be found in the next link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx

Although it probably appears that it is very small executable file, comparing the same .cpp file compiled in Linux with g++ shows a considerable difference.

`g++ name.cpp` -> 9,0KB executable size

And optimizing it a bit:

`g++ -O2 -s -DNDEBUG name.cpp` -> 6,3 KB executable size

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the weight even further?

Answer (score 3):

Your code pulls in the IOstreams part of the standard library, as implemented by Microsoft. That means it also needs the synchronization with C stdio, and support for constructors of globals.

Also, the default build is a debug build. The obvious switch to test would be `/O1` (optimize for size). An unused integer variable should add 0 bytes in release builds. `/DNDEBUG` should eliminate asserts.

Comment: I managed to get down to 40kb, with nothing but `int main(){return 0;}` and `/O1` argument

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

.cpp is a sketch, while .exe is a working machine, which has to open a console, write down your string, be able to terminate itself. I believe that is what takes most of program's space.

Comment: About half of what you describe is done by Windows itself. Windows opens the console. You have to provide the string to Windows, but it will then write that string to the console. Termination is the most complex, with MSVCRT calling the Windows `TerminateProcess` function. But literally the biggest part of that call is the name `"TerminateProcess"`! The call itself is ~8 bytes.